# UITextView custom UIDataDetectorTypes

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate, datadetectortypes

I have read a lot of posts about this yet, but I didn't get to a good result. I would like to, for example, have a `UIDetectorType` for Hashtags in a `UITextView`.

Isn't there a way to subclass to accomplish this? It seems odd of apple to just have these detector types and no customization(as they even have a twitter-keyboard in the SDK).

Is there an approach but laying buttons over the text where it's necessary?

Comment: I'd suggest to detect hastags (with a `NSRegularExpression`), using `NSAttributedString`, put a `NSLinkAttributeName` and custom the rending.

Comment: Good Idea! Didn't know of NSLinkAttributeName. Seems like this is new in iOS 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the tintColor of the UITextView. It affects the link color as well as the cursor line and the selected text color.